# A note about us from the real world

Tags: discussion

Since we're a purely online community (well, I assume there aren't some of us who do meet in the real world), I thought it would be nice to share a piece of information I learned today concerning our site.

My mom is a published author and was attending a panel about writing. One of the panelists was a NASA engineer who said that learning how the sciences interact with each other, getting those effects right, and creating consistency in the world help engage readers. He specifically brought up the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange as a good place to go to get feedback about those issues.

So congratulations to everyone for helping to create a useful site that really does have an impact in the world! (The real Earth, of course...)

And, if that NASA engineer happens to see this post: Thank you for bringing attention to our community!

Comment: Awesome. A link to this is now going to be my response to anyone who disses the use of science on Worldbuilding.

Comment: I don't suppose the panel was posted on youtube or anything?

Comment: @TimB Not that I know of. I provided here all the information I was given.

Comment: Wait ... what is this 'real world' of which you speak?

Comment: @randal'thor I think it's one of Larry Niven's settings.

Comment: @randal'thor I think we have a tag for it... [science-based]/[hard-science] [earth], as I recall. We don't seem to use it all that much, so maybe I'm mistaken.